# assembly naming conventions

Tags: c#, naming-conventions, shared-libraries

Assuming you have a namespace that is useful to more than one project in your company, in the format of "MyCompany.Core", would you have an assembly named exactly the same way or just "Core". Why or why not?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Use the standard .NET naming conventions, assembly names are [covered here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms229048.aspx).  I'll save you the (short) read:

> Do choose names for your assembly DLLs
>   that suggest large chunks of
>   functionality such as System.Data.
>   Assembly and DLL names do not have to
>   correspond to namespace names but it
>   is reasonable to follow the namespace
>   name when naming assemblies.
>
> Consider naming DLLs according to the
>   following pattern: 
>     `<Company>.<Component>.dll`
>   Where `<Component>` contains one or more
>   dot-separated clauses.
>
> For example, Contoso.WebControls.dll.

Comment: Any tips for doing the assembly name refactoring (Resharper?), at least within the same VS solution?

Comment: Project + Properties, Application tab, Assembly name.

Answer (score 5):

I believe it's best (opinion here!) to name the assembly after the root namespace it contains, in your case **MyCompany.Core.dll**.  You never know if that file will make its way outside the company, and keeping track of it is just easier in general.

Imagine if Microsoft named System.Core just `Core.dll` *(System.Core)*, then you had `Core.dll` *(MyCompany.Core)*....you imagine how that gets hairy fast.

Answer (score 4):

I would name the assembly the same as the root namespace.  This makes it easy to figure out what code is in which assembly, and prevents collisions with other projects (from other companies) that might also be using the ambiguious name "Core.dll".

Answer (score 4):

I prefer MyCompany.ApplicationName.Core.DLL, this eliminates the chances of conflict if there are two or more applications from MyCompany.

Answer (score 0):

if developing in a enterprise environment, this convention may be useful:

Namespaces follow the [DomainEntityName].[AssemblyName].[Purpose].[RelatedPurpose] format where the DomainEntityName is the root business functionality name and the AssemblyName is the functionally that is supporting the Business requirement.

Answer (score 0):

Based on Microsoft [DLL naming conventions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/design-guidelines/names-of-assemblies-and-dlls), I prefer the following pattern:

```
<Company>.<AppName>.<FeatureName>.<Layer>.dll
```

For example:

***MyCompany.Sandwichery.Ordering.API***

***MyCompany.Sandwichery.Ordering.Domain***

***MyCompany.Sandwichery.Ordering.Infrastructure***